# Updating RestKit to master

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I updated to master and I'm not able to load new classes like 
RKObjectMapping.  I went through the install instructions again and reviewed 
the example projects but still can't figure it out.  Why wouldn't XCode know 
about RKObjectMapping when I include ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem as well.

From [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/f52b75edd88dd59c) on the RestKit group:

1. Close the project
2. Open Window->Organizer
3. Under Projects tab, delete DerivedData for your project
4. Quit Xcode and Relaunch
5. Open the project
6. Clean and rebuild

Everything should work.